# what would be the initial values

Tags: ocaml

```
let gen_xy vals comp o = 
  List.fold_left ( fun a ( x, y ) -> comp ( fst a ) x, comp ( snd a ) y ) o vals

let max_xy vals = gen_xy vals max ( min_int, min_int )
```

What would be the initial value assigned to min_int at the time when 
`max_xy [ (1,2);(3,4) ]` is entered at the #prompt?

Thanks for any input

Answer (score 3):

`min_int` is a global constant, whose value is system dependent. On a 64 bit system (with a 64 bit version of ocaml to go with it), it will be -4611686018427387904.

Note that the value of `min_int` will not change during the run of your program, so talking about `min_int`'s "initial value" is a bit misleading.